# Invoke maven-invoker-plugin in a specific phase

Tags: maven, maven-invoker-plugin

Is it possible to execute goal of maven-invoker-plugin in a specific phase only? I want the goal to execute only when i run 'mvn verify' and not when 'mvn install' is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `mvn` with a specific phase will run the lifecycle up to that phase. This means that  `mvn install` will run all phases including `install`. This means that `mvn install` will always run `verify` as well. So you cannot achieve what you want to achive.

But maybe if you give more information about your ultimate goal, it will be possible to find a solution that works for you.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am invoking another pom from a pom. I want the other pom to invoke only in verify phase but not in install phase. As you mentioned, it seems difficult to achieve it.

Comment: What do you want achieve with "invoking another pom"? Why should it be done when calling verify, but not when calling install?